# Why were the code points in the range of U+D800 to U+DFFF removed from the Unicode character set?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

I am learning about UTF-16 encoding, and I have read that if you want to represent code points in the range of U+10000 to U+10FFFF, then you have to use surrogate pairs, which are in the range of U+D800 to U+DFFF.

So let's say I want to encode the following code point: U+10123 (10000000100100011 in binary):

First I layout this sequence of bits:

110110xxxxxxxxxx 110111xxxxxxxxxx

Then I fill the places with the x with the binary format of the code point:

1101100001000000 1101110100100011 (D840 DD23 in hexadecimal)

---

I have also read that the code points in the range of U+D800 to U+DFFF were removed from the Unicode character set, but I don't understand why this range was removed!

I mean this range can be easily encoded in 4 bytes, for example the following is the UTF-16 encoded format of the U+D812 code point (1101100000010010 in binary):

1101100000110110 1101110000010010 (D836 DC12 in hexadecimal)

***Note:*** I was using UTF-16 Big Endian in my examples.

Comment: Are you sure that U+10123 becomes `D840 DD23` and not `D800 DD23`?

Comment: @Roland Illig It's weird, when I encode it manually I get `D840 DD23`, but when I encode it using this online tool: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/, I get `D800 DD23`. Is my manual encoding method wrong?

Comment: Let's call it reserved instead of removed.  Aids in error detection, you can tell who got it wrong and file the bug report in the right place.  Other examples are U+FFFE (matches backwards BOM) and U+FFFF (too easy to get wrong as C end-of-file).

Comment: @Roland Illig You are right, `D800 DD23` is the correct answer, what I did wrong is that I forgot to subtract `0x10000` from the code point (this should have been the first step I make).

Answer (score 12):

Codepoints U+D800 - U+DFFF are *reserved exclusively*<sup>1</sup> for use with UTF-16.  Since they are not in the range of U+10000 - U+10FFFF, UTF-16 would not encode them individually using surrogate pairs, so it would be ambiguous (and *illegal*<sup>2</sup>) for these individual codepoints to appear un-encoded in a UTF-16 sequence.

---

Per the [Unicode.org UTF-16 FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html):

<sup>1</sup>: [Q: What are surrogates?](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1)

> A: Surrogates are code points from two special ranges of Unicode values, **reserved for use as the leading, and trailing values of paired code units in UTF-16**. Leading, also called high, surrogates are from D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>, and trailing, or low, surrogates are from DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub>. They are called surrogates, since **they do not represent characters directly, but only as a pair**.

<sup>2</sup>: [Q: Are there any 16-bit values that are invalid?](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-7)

> A: **Unpaired surrogates are invalid in UTFs**. These include any value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub> not followed by a value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub>, or any value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub> not preceded by a value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>.

Comment: Your wording is mixing encoded code points with code points.  They can not be unencoded in a UTF-16 stream. There is no way to encode them in UTF-16.  UTF-8 and UTF-32 can encode them, but as you pointed out, they are reserved and should not be encoded.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an official source to back this up, but I believe it was to prevent confusion, so that you couldn't get a code sequence that could be interpreted as both valid UTF-16 and valid UCS-2. The loss of 2048 code points was nothing compared to the addition of 1048576 new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Since encoding a code point as surrogate pair starts by subtracting `0x010000`, this would lead to negative numbers. And the point of this subtraction is to allow 65536 more code points instead of encoding the left-out 2048. Maybe this will prove useful, should the whole code space be used up in a distant future.

Comment: Only codepoints U+10000 - U+10FFFF are subtracted and encoded to surrogate pairs.  Codepoints U+0000 - U+FFFF are encoded as-is, not subtracted.

Comment: @Remy That's why I said "encoding a code point _as surrogate pair_".