# ValueError: Unpaired high surrogate when decoding 'string' on reading json file

Tags: python, json, file

I am currently working on python 3.8.6. I am getting the following error on reading (thousands of) json files in python:

```
ValueError: Unpaired high surrogate when decoding 'string' on reading json file
```

I tried using the following solutions while checking other stackoverflow posts but nothing worked:

```
1) import json
   json.loads('{"":"\\ud800"}')

2) import simplejson
   simplejson.loads('{"":"\\ud800"}')
```

The problem is that after getting this error the remaining json files are not read. Is there a way to get rid of this error so I can read all the json files?

I am not sure what all information is necessary to provide regarding the problem so please feel free to ask.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for looking into it. the problem is that after getting this error the remaining json files are not read. Is there a way to get rid of this error so I can read all the json files?

Comment: If you can guess what the missing data is, add it back.  My answer has some more details around this.

Comment: The examples you provide do not raise an exception. It is some other part of your code that is encountering a problem with the data.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode code point U+D800 [may only occur as part of a surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187609/14637) (and then only in UTF-16 encoding). So that string inside the JSON is (after decoding it) not valid UTF-8.

The JSON itself might or might not be valid. [The spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf) doesn't mention the case of unmatched surrogate pairs, but does explicitly allow nonexistent code points:

> To  escape  a  code  point  that  is  not  in  the  Basic  Multilingual  Plane,  the  character  may  be  represented  as  a twelve-character  sequence,  encoding  the  UTF-16  surrogate  pair  corresponding  to  the  code  point.  So  for example, a string containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as "\uD834\uDD1E". However, whether a processor of JSON texts interprets such a surrogate pair as a single code point or as an explicit surrogate pair is a semantic decision that is determined by the specific processor.
>
> Note  that  the  JSON  grammar  permits  code  points  for  which  Unicode  does  not  currently  provide  character assignments.

Now, you can choose your friends, but you can't choose your family and you can't always choose your JSON either. So the next question is: how to parse this mess?

It looks like both the built-in `json` module in Python (version 3.9) and `simplejson` (version 3.17.2) have no problems parsing the JSON. The problem only occurs once you try to use the string. So this really doesn't have anything to do with JSON at all:

```
>>> bork = '\ud800'
>>> bork
'\ud800'
>>> print(bork)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Fortunately, we can encode the string manually and tell Python how to handle the error. For example, replace the erroneous code point with a question mark:

```
>>> bork.encode('utf-8', errors='replace')
b'?'
```

The documentation lists [other possible options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) for the `errors` argument.

To fix up this broken string, we can encode (into `bytes`) and then decode (back into `str`):

```
>>> bork.encode('utf-8', errors='replace').decode('utf-8')
'?'
```

Answer (score 0):

A Unicode [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) in isolation does not correspond to anything.  Every valid high surrogate code point needs to be immediately followed by a low surrogate code point before it can be meaningfully decoded.

The error message simply means that this code point in isolation does not have a well-defined meaning. It's like saying "take" without saying what we should take, or "look at" without the object of the sentence filled in.

You should not be using surrogates in files which do not contain UTF-16 anyway; they are reserved strictly for this encoding.  It is used for encoding characters outside the 16-bit space which this 16-bit encoding can naturally represent by way of splitting them across two code points.

The simple and obvious fix is to supply the missing information, but we can't know what it is. Perhaps you have more context, and can fill in with a correct low surrogate pair.  But for example, this works:

```
>>> json.loads('{"":"\\ud800\\udc00"}')
{'': ''}
```

It populates the JSON with the single code point [U+010000](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/10000.html) but of course we can have no idea whether that's actually the code point your data should contain.

Comment: Strangely enough, inside JSON, surrogate pairs may be used to encode code points outside the BMP (see the last paragraphs of [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf)).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for pointing that out; added a brief sentence about this.  I'll repeat again that this is not a valid use of surrogate pairs; JSON should normally not use this (though there are [legacy reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463038/why-does-json-encode-utf-16-surrogate-pairs-instead-of-unicode-code-points-direc)).